# Custom map overlays using Marble

Tags: c++, qt, marble

I'm trying to create custom overlays in [Marble](https://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/index.html) while following [this](https://techbase.kde.org/Marble/DisplayGeoDataGroundOverlay) tutorial. My code is identical to the one in the example.

Everything seems ok, but somehow the generated layer is editable and I can click it and change its size.

I'd like it to be just static on the background with no way of interacting with it.

There doesn't seem to be any obvious flag to set or function to override (so that I could just ignore all user events).

Any ideas?

---

Code as requested:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QImage>

#include <marble/MarbleWidget.h>
#include <marble/GeoDataDocument.h>
#include <marble/GeoDataGroundOverlay.h>
#include <marble/GeoDataTreeModel.h>
#include <marble/MarbleModel.h>

using namespace Marble;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QFileInfo inputFile( app.arguments().last() );
    if ( app.arguments().size() < 2 || !inputFile.exists() ) {
        qWarning() << "Usage: " << app.arguments().first() << "file.png";
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a Marble QWidget without a parent
    MarbleWidget *mapWidget = new MarbleWidget();

    // Load the Satellite map
    mapWidget->setMapThemeId( "earth/bluemarble/bluemarble.dgml" );

    // Create a bounding box from the given corner points
    GeoDataLatLonBox box( 55, 48, 14.5, 6, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );
    box.setRotation( 0, GeoDataCoordinates::Degree );

    // Create an overlay and assign the image to render and its bounding box to it
    GeoDataGroundOverlay *overlay = new GeoDataGroundOverlay;
    overlay->setLatLonBox( box );
    overlay->setIcon( QImage( inputFile.absoluteFilePath() ) );

    // Create a document as a container for the overlay
    GeoDataDocument *document = new GeoDataDocument();
    document->append( overlay );

    // Add the document to MarbleWidget's tree model
    mapWidget->model()->treeModel()->addDocument( document );

    mapWidget->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You can programatically enable/disable plugins using `RenderPlugin` and `setVisible`:

```
QList<RenderPlugin *> renderPluginList = marbleWidget->renderPlugins();
for (RenderPlugin *renderPlugin : renderPluginList) {
  if (std::find(plugin_list.begin(), plugin_list.end(), renderPlugin->nameId()) != plugin_list.end())
  {
     renderPlugin->setVisible(true);
  }
  else
  {
     renderPlugin->setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Where `plugin_list` is a `std::vector<QString>` of plugin `nameId()`s.

To disable just the Annotation plugin, you could use:

```
QList<RenderPlugin *> renderPluginList = mapWidget->renderPlugins();
for (RenderPlugin *renderPlugin : renderPluginList) {
  if (renderPlugin->nameId() == "annotation")
  {
     renderPlugin->setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

---

In case you are still experiencing this issue, one thing to check is whether you have the `AnnotationPlugin` (`.dll` if on Windows) in the `plugins/` directory. This plugin allows for moving and resizing various features on the `MarbleWidget` map.